# Given E[X] and Var[X], what is P(X=0)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $E[X]=\theta(n^{1.5})$ , $Var[X]=\theta(n^{2.5})$ , $X \ge 0$

What can you say about $P(X=0)$ using Chebyshev's inequality?

**A**: $P(X=0)=O(1/n^2)$

**B**: $P(X=0)=O(1/n^{1.5})$

**C**: $P(X=0)=O(1/n)$

**D**: $P(X=0)=O(1/n^{0.5})$

The original question required to find $E[X]$ and $Var[X]$, and i found them, and they're correct.

To solve this part of the question, i tried using the following Chebyshev's inequality:
$${\bf P(X \ge b)=\frac{1}{2}P(|X-E[X]| \ge \alpha \sigma) \le \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha^2}} \space\space,\space\space\alpha\sigma =b-E[X]\space\space,\space\space\sigma=\sqrt{Var}$$
So i said:

$P(X=0)=P(X<1)=1-P(X \ge 1)$

And now i can apply Chebyshev's inequality:

$P(X \ge 1)=\frac{1}{2}P(|X-n^{1.5}| \ge \alpha \sigma) \le \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$

$\alpha\sigma=1-n^{1.5}$

$\sigma=\sqrt{Var}=n^{1.25}$

$\alpha=\frac{1-n^{1.5}}{n^{1.25}}$

$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\alpha^2}=\frac{n^{2.5}}{2(1-n^{1.5})^2}=O(n^{0.5})$

Hence:
$$P(X=0)=1-P(X \ge 1) \ge 1-\frac{1}{n^{0.5}}$$

**The correct answer should be D.** What was wrong in my solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please use `\Theta` in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $P(X \ge 1)=\frac{1}{2}P(|X-n^{1.5}| \ge \alpha \sigma)$ ... (where) ... $\alpha\sigma=1-n^{1.5}$

No idea why you think this holds. Note that with your choice of $\alpha\sigma$, $|X(\omega)-n^{1.5}| \geqslant \alpha \sigma$ is true for every $n\geqslant1$ and every $\omega$.

On the other hand, $[X=0]\subseteq[|X-E[X]|\geqslant E[X]]$ hence Chebychev inequality applied to the event on the RHS yields $P[X=0]\leqslant\mathrm{Var}[X]/E[X]^2$. By hypothesis, $\mathrm{Var}[X]\leqslant an^{5/2}$ and $E[X]\geqslant bn^{3/2}$ hence $P[X=0]\leqslant c/n^{1/2}$ with $c=a/b^2$. QED.

Answer (score 0):

The probability mass $p = P(X=0)$ has a *moment of inertia* (about the center of mass at $\Theta(n^{1.5})$) that has value $p[\Theta(n^{1.5})]^2 = p\Theta(n^3)$. But since the *variance* (which is the
total moment of inertia of *all* the probability masses about the center of mass)
is $\Theta(n^{2.5})$, it must be that $p$ is $O(n^{-0.5})$, since any
larger mass will give a variance that exceeds $\Theta(n^{2.5})$.